# What does the error "Failed to load HAR file with following error: First parameter is expected to be an object" mean when trying to upload a HAR file?

Tags: performance, error-handling, developer-tools, har

I tried uploading a 147KB HAR file to Developer Tools on Edge and I get the error message "Failed to load HAR file with following error: First parameter is expected to be an object". When I try uploading to Google Chrome Developer Tools it doesn't give an error message but shows no data at all (almost like it never actually uploaded). What does this mean about the HAR file?

I tried uploading a 147KB HAR file to Developer Tools on Edge and I get the error message "Failed to load HAR file with following error: First parameter is expected to be an object". When I try uploading to Google Chrome Developer Tools it doesn't give an error message but shows no data at all (almost like it never actually uploaded).

I was expecting the HAR file to show me data that my client collected so I can review performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try HttpWatch Studio in our free HttpWatch Basic download. It may give you a more detailed error message:

https://www.httpwatch.com/download/